# Correct result wrap in dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using the `DataGridView` and `Wrap="True"`.

But when I type in text into the DataGridView. Text goes up inside the cell. But I want the whole row from the DataGridView to come down automatically.

Incorrect result:

[image]

The correct result:

[image]

What's the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ensuring text wraps in a dataGridView column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325759/ensuring-text-wraps-in-a-datagridview-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to  set

`AutoSizeRowsMode = DisplayedCell`

and

`RowDefaultCellStyle: WrapText=True`

Comment: It comes with an incorrect result. (First Picture)


  But I like the second picture

Comment: It should work. I checked this by creating new Form with blank datagrid and having 3 cells in it. You will see the auto-resize row once you lost the focus from current cell. 

May be try adding separate grid for test to check the solution. if this doesn't work then let me know which are the other properties you already set to your grid.

Comment: thank. it work. How can I get an order with the number of line DataGridView. For example, in picture number two. Line= 8

Comment: I'm glad that it worked! you should mark this as answer..


-- I didn't got your point. how would you like to calculate the line = 8 ?

Comment: in picture 2: Row1 = 2 Line & Row2 = 1 Line & Row3 = 4 Line & Row4 = 1 Line. -----> Line = 8.