# C# String Measurements

Tags: c#, winforms, string, units-of-measurement

I want to measure the length of a string into pixel units. I searched the web for 2 days but got no luck. Finally, I found some code snippet a few minutes ago from a blog and modified it a little bit. Here's my function:

```
private void cmdMeasure_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Font fntStyle = new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(str2measure.Text, fntStyle);
    MessageBox.Show(textSize.ToString());
}
```

Question:

What is the unit of 16? Is it em, pt, or the unit of GraphicsUnit enum? I don't really get the description defined by c# "the em-size of the new font in the units specified by the unit parameter."

Does the TextRenderer.MeasureText method include the spaces between the characters in its measurement?

Comment: Following the docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141987.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphicsunit.aspx) shows that the 16 is in units of pixels, since the parameter `GraphicsUnit.Pixel` is supplied to the Font constructor.

Comment: It would be in Pixels thanks to the GraphicsUnit.Pixel, and would mean for most fonts - the height of the capital letter W. Characters can naturally overlap and the measurement will return the final size from left-side to right-side plus edge-padding. You can also use Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451903/how-can-i-convert-a-string-length-to-a-pixel-unit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the unit of 16? Is it em, pt, or the unit of GraphicsUnit
>   enum? I don't really get the description defined by c# "the em-size of
>   the new font in the units specified by the unit parameter."

As others have said, it's pixels since you pass GraphicsUnit.Pixel.

> Does the TextRenderer.MeasureText method include the spaces between
>   the characters in its measurement?

Yes.  It gives you the dimensions of the bounding box around the whole block of text.

Comment: I tried to measure the string "a" and it returned a width of 17 and height of 18. So are you saying that the width or height minus 16 equals to the thickness of the bounding box?

Comment: The 17x18 dimensions simply mean that an "a" drawn on screen in Arial with a size 16 font would fit nicely inside a 17x18 rectangle.  Think of it as the area "used" to display the text.

Comment: Yes.  Check the docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`TextRenderer.MeasureString` does take in account the spaces.  In your example, the number 16 is in pixels.

Although, I'm not sure you are measuring your string correctly.  I think you need to get your Font from your `str2measure` textbox:

```
Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(str2measure.Text, str2measure.Font);
```

Comment: I tried to change the font property of str2measure.Text but the function returned the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Ans Q1. It is pixels only as you are passing GraphicsUnit.Pixel

Ans Q2. It is considering the entire text block no matter what is the content even white spaces.