# How to Calculate String Length in Pixels

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to know how to get a string's length in pixels in C# Unity3D.

```
  string msg = ""You Must be from South Carolina!";
```

How do I get the above message string length in Pixels?.

Comment: First, what have you already tried. Second, the size of text in pixels will depend on (at the very least) the rendering method. So a good start would be to specify how you're actually rendering this string onscreen.

Comment: Something similar was already answered here before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451903/how-can-i-convert-a-string-length-to-a-pixel-unit Hopefully this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way you can get the width of your String. Nb: You should know what font you use :

```
string msg = "You Must be from South Carolina!";
Font stringFont = new Font("Arial", 12);

using (Bitmap tempImage = new Bitmap(400,400)) 
{
    SizeF stringSize = Graphics.FromImage(tempImage).MeasureString(msg , stringFont);
    double width = stringSize.Width;
}
```

Comment: Which Name space `SizeF` avaialble?.@Ksven.

Comment: It's in System.Drawing. You should reference the assembly System.Drawing.dll if it's not the case.

Comment: I got This error :  The type or namespace name `SizeF' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?.So what i can do for this?.@Ksven

Comment: You need to add a using statement to the top of your code, e.g. using System.Drawing and you should add a reference to System.Drawing.DLL if its not already referenced.